# PHP Session Variables Not Working

Tags: php, variables, session, web, server-side

I need help with PHP session variables. I am registering them, and then they print fine from the same page, but other pages are not getting them correctly.

Here is the page that is setting them

```
if($logIn){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['name'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $check[1];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['addr'] = $check[3];
    echo $_SESSION['name']." is ";
    echo "logged in";
} else {
    echo "nogo";
}
fclose($fp);
```

and then the page linked to has

```
<body>
<?php include '../header.php'; ?>
<?php echo $_SESSION['name']."lets go"; ?>
```

And it will not print anything...can't figure this out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they 2 separate files? If they are, in the second file you have to make sure to call `session_start()` again

Answer (score 8):

`session_start();` start *must* got at the top of every page *before* any output. Make sure on the second page you have that at the top of the page or else you will get no output from session variables.